# Is it possible to refresh SEDE daily?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I'm currently working on changing [http to https in questions and answers of mine](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1447789/clean-up-your-http-links). To not flood the homepage (SF&F doesn't have the volume SO has), I do about 5 a day. When I run the query the next day, the ones I've already fixed are still among the results. It would be nice to be able to get a new list of only the posts I still have to edit, but the SEDE is only refreshed on Sundays.

Is it possible to increase the frequency and refresh SEDE daily?

I'm sure this would come in handy for a *lot* of other queries as well. And while I can certainly work around it, simply by *remembering which ones I've done already*, that wouldn't work if we were to adapt the query to find *all* cases, regardless of user ID. And I can imagine a number of other queries that would benefit from a more frequent refresh.

Comment: As a workaround you could run the query once, download the file and each day delete the lines you have done.

Comment: Considering the answer, this seems like it might be a really good support question - particularly since rene is already offering suggestions on how to avoid your issue. :) That said, I'm not sure if a support version of this would be a duplicate or not.

Comment: Another alternative, for your specific case: vanilla site search. It doesn't look like search plays nice with excluding a bunch of domains, like the SEDE query supports, but it can still pull all of your posts with unsecure HTTP links [with `user:19561 url:"http://*"`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A19561+url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F*%22)

Comment: @zcoop98 unfortunately, there are a lot of sites that (still) do not support https. One of those is isfdb.org, which is used a _lot_ on [fantasy.se], yielding a lot of posts that can't be fixed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

I don't think it is wise to do.

Refreshing SEDE takes 6 to 8 hours on Sunday. During that time you'll notice SEDE is struggling to perform queries as quickly as it does during the week.

When a refresh is on its way, there is always one database "extra", [the famous _temp database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309917/whats-the-codegolf-temp-database-and-why-does-it-mess-up-my-query/309919#309919) as that is the one currently being restored. This is a pain for those queries that run over all databases. They either break or report stats over incomplete data.

The progress report on the refresh isn't great. You can't really see how far we  are. Once a week this is manageable with [a nifty query](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc) but having to deal with this every day is a bit too much of a pain.

For your use case: can't you rely on your browser to show you which links you already visited? Alternatively, use a sensible order by and add a "start from" paramater that you keep track of yourself.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know refreshing it takes such a long time. That certainly explains why it can't be done more frequently.

Comment: *Alternatively, use a sensible order by and add a "start from" paramater that you keep track of yourself.* That's exactly what my [Broken Image Repairer](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) does. One can either use `created:` or `lastactive:` for manual searches: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching